# Dynamically Assign Type in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Does anyone know if this is possible or advisable?

I would like to create a class that can cycle through values in Core Data. When the class is initialised the user will indicate the name of each attribute/column and the type.

I was hoping I could assign values to a variable in the manner indicated below.

However, the problem occurs when I try to dynamically assign a type to the variable, visible in the last bit of code below (**as col.type**). I'm aware that this may look a little clumsy but I'm trying to communicate *what* I'd like to do as much as anything.

**Class definition:**

```
class TargetColumnDetail {
    var columnNameCore:String!
    var columnNameParse:String!
    var type:NSObject.Type!

    init(){}
}
```

**Initialization:**

```
var col: TargetColumnDetail = TargetColumnDetail()
col.columnNameCore = "name"
col.columnNameParse = "name"
col.type = NSString.self
```

**How I imagine it would be used:**

```
    for col:TargetColumnDetail in self.targetColumnDetails{
        var coreValue = coreDataObject.valueForKey(col.columnNameCore) as col.type    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using generics something like the following:

```
class TargetColumnDetail<T> {

    var columnNameCore:String!
    var columnNameParse:String!

    func valueForKey(coreDataObject:NSManagedObject)->T{

        return coreDataObject.valueForKey(col.columnNameCore) as T
    }

}
```

and then use as follow

```
for col:TargetColumnDetail in self.targetColumnDetails{
    var coreValue = col.valueForKey(coreDataObject)    
}
```